# Can you use WHERE logic to fetch data through a pivot table in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Is it possible to turn the following code below into one line?

```
// Fetch the producer role
$Roles = Role::where('label', '=', 'Producer')->get();
$role = $Roles->first();

// Fetch the producers
$Producers = Role::find($role->role_id)->users()->get();
```

Also here is what my Pivot table logic looks like (inside Role):

```
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'UsersRoles', 'role_id', 'user_id');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but why would you want to squash it to one line? Apart from being it completely redundant..

```
// 1st query, load collection of roles...
$Roles = Role::where('label', '=', 'Producer')->get();
// ... just to use one of them?
$role = $Roles->first();

$Producers = 
    // run another query to get the same role...
    Role::find($role->role_id)
    ->users()->get();
```

Anyway, here's one-liner:

```
$producers = Role::where('lable', 'Producer')->first()->users;
// or
$producers = Role::where('lable', 'Producer')->with('users')->first()->users;
```

Comment: Thanks man.  I only needed to fetch users with the producer role.  I don't need any of the other data.  New to Laravel and not sure if there was an easier way to do this where it would only be one query with a LEFT JOIN.